# Proving uniform convergence of a sequence

Tags: uniform-convergence

I have to prove the uniform convergence of this sequence $f_n(x)=\tan^{-1}nx$ in $[a,b],a>0$

What I have reached so far:

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left|\tan^{-1}nx-\frac\pi 2\right|=\tan^{-1}nx-\frac\pi 2<\epsilon$$

How do I proceed further ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have edited the question to include the interval

Comment: @AmanMittal Alright, it would even work with $[a,\infty)$ provided $a>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recalling the Taylor series of $\arctan(t)$ at $t=\infty$

$$ \frac{\pi}{2} -{\frac {1}{t}}+O \left( {t}^{-3} \right)  $$

$$  \implies \arctan( nx )=\frac{\pi}{2}-{\frac {1}{ny}}+O \left( {n}^{-3} \right) 
 $$

$$ \implies \arctan( nx )-\frac{\pi}{2}= -\frac{1}{nx}+O \left( {n}^{-3} \right) $$

$$ \implies \arctan( nx )-\frac{\pi}{2} \sim -\frac{1}{nx}. $$

Now, you can advance to finish the problem.

Comment: Nice!! so $m$ may be chosen as any value greater than $-1\over \epsilon x$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\tan^{-1} x=\frac\pi 2$ means that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x_0$ such that $x>x_0$ implies $\left|\tan^{-1}x-\frac\pi2\right|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I have already reached that far (as indicated). The problem is what should i do after this

Comment: @AmanMittal Use the fact that $\arctan$ is monotonic.